# DHCP over Ubuntu for Embedded System

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, dhcp, embedded-system

I have an embedded Linux system running Ubuntu connected via Ethernet to my laptop which is also running Ubuntu. My laptop is connected to my home network via wifi. I would like to create a local network between my laptop and the board (Altera DE1-SoC) over Ethernet with this network connected to my home network over the wifi NIC in my laptop. Ideally I would like to allow the embedded system to perform DCHP discover on my home network to get its own IP address. What are the major configurations/steps I need to take to do this?
The interfaces on my laptop are

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ec:f4:bb:9c:2f:35  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:736 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5148 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:251712 (251.7 KB)  TX bytes:943851 (943.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1303331 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1303331 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:504332328 (504.3 MB)  TX bytes:504332328 (504.3 MB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:88:69:70:16:d8  
          inet addr:192.168.1.148  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2601:4b:500:1d01:c03a:e05e:9c30:b44e/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::1095:5763:9405:b652/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2601:4b:500:1d01:774f:fccd:5479:e9bc/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6588443 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2426855 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6843503929 (6.8 GB)  TX bytes:502932524 (502.9 MB)
```

I believe enp1s0 corresponds to the Ethernet NIC and wlp2s0 corresponds to the wireless NIC.

On the board I have

```
jfrye@DE1-SoC:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr da:e9:a5:9c:c8:58
          inet6 addr: fe80::d8e9:a5ff:fe9c:c858/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:577 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:197334 (197.3 KB)  TX bytes:175844 (175.8 KB)
          Interrupt:31 Base address:0x4000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:6016 (6.0 KB)  TX bytes:6016 (6.0 KB)
```

/etc/network/interfaces on laptop

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo wlp2s0
iface lo inet loopback

auto lo enp1s0
iface enps1s0 inet dhcp
```

/etc/network/interfaces on board

```
#interfaces (5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

When I ifdown and ifup eth0 on the board, I get

```
Listening on LPF/eth0/da:e9:a5:9c:c8:58
Sending on   LPF/eth0/da:e9:a5:9c:c8:58
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xb785c867)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0xb785c867)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
```

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are asking for is very difficult to implement, as it requires 4-address Wi-Fi headers. Each Wi-Fi packet can contain 4 MAC addresses - a starting and ending ethernet address and a starting and ending Wi-Fi address. However, in most home applications, the ending ethernet address isn't needed, as the ending Wi-Fi address typically refers to the same device (think your phone or laptop). So, many home Wi-Fi routers block any traffic using 4-address headers, supposedly for security reasons.

I attempted a similar task - we had an ethernet-only server that we wanted to attach to our Wi-Fi network. We didn't have a Wi-Fi dongle or card on hand, but we did have lots of Raspberry Pis, so we decided to simply use a Pi as our adapter. However, we ran into this very issue.

Going forward, you have several options (that I know of):

- See if your router supports 4-address packets, in which case you will only have to bridge the networks on your laptop - every router is different, and yours just might support 4-address routing.
- Create a subnet on your computer for you to communicate with the embedded device, while connected to your Wi-Fi - this can be accomplished using a DHCP server running on the ethernet interface. You can also implement NAT to allow the embedded device access to your Wi-Fi network and the internet. However, you'll have to port-forward if you want the embedded device to be accessible from the Wi-Fi network.
- Directly pass packets between the interfaces on the laptop, effectively removing it from the network. This is the route we took with the Pis. We used [wlan_kabel](https://github.com/escitalopram/wlan_kabel). I even wrote a quick [setup script](https://github.com/abermeister479/WiFiBridge) for a Pi that would probably run on Ubuntu (if you disable netplan). Under this scheme, the network sees the embedded device as having the Wi-Fi MAC address of the laptop. We had issues using DHCP (likely because the wired computer ignored DHCPOFFERS with the wrong address), so I'd recommend using a static IP with this route.

Sorry I wasn't able to provide an optimal solution - AFAIK, the hardware doesn't support it. Let me know if you come up with a better one, so I can implement that with our Pis as well.